# how to get `zip` to add .zip extension when the filename is constructed from a variable

Tags: bash, zip

If I run...

```
$ myTest="bar"
$ zip -r foo-${myTest} path/*
```

...then I get a zip file named `foo-bar.zip`. (note the `.zip` extension!) However, if I run...

```
$ myTest="1.0.1"
$ zip -r foo-${myTest} path/*
```

...then I get a zip file named `foo-1.0.1`. (no `.zip` extension!)

I can obviously add `.zip` to my script, but I would like to understand what is going on here. Why doesn't `zip` add the extension when the filename is built from a variable with numbers in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dawned on me as I wrote that last question that this isn't about numbers. Quoting from `man zip`:

> If the name of the zip archive does not contain an extension, the extension .zip is added. If the name already contains  an  extension  other  than .zip,  the existing  extension  is kept unchanged.  However, split archives (archives split over multiple files) require the .zip extension on the last split.

The problem is that I have `.`'s in the variable, which `zip` interprets as filename extensions. Luckily, my script constructs the variable with `.`'s so I can confidently add `.zip` to the end. Otherwise, I would need to test for `.`'s to name the file correctly.